# Etymology of "С дуба рухнуть"

Tags: этимология, выражения, saying

The expression `С дуба рухнуть` means: `crack up, go nuts`. For example:

> Ты что, с дуба рухнул?
>   *Have you lost it?*

What is the etymology of this expression?

Comment: What does the expression mean by the way?

Comment: @Alenanno: `crack up`, `go nuts` (`Ты что, с дуба рухнул?` - `Have you lost it?`)

Comment: Ahahah nice! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an interesting theory [in a blog post](http://ru-ace.livejournal.com/11612.html). I don't know if it's true, but then, it's an interesting theory.

> ДУБ, он же Мировое Дерево - характерный для мифопоэтического сознания
>   образ, воплощающий универсальную концепцию мира: противопоставление
>   хаоса организованному космосу. Людей издревле удивляли необъяснимые
>   явления природы, в частности, такие как сезонное опадение листьев: "С
>   Дуба падали листья ясеня..." - гласит одна из народных песен-былин.
>   Великий же русский поэт А.С.Пушкин воспел ДУБ в стихотворении,
>   известном каждому еще со школы: "У Лукоморья Дуб зеленый" - по
>   которому мы можем узнать, как выглядел Российский вариант arbor mundi
>   до недавнего времени. Ибо после революции этот памятник был уничтожен
>   как архаизм и буржуазное излишество (о чем поется в городском романсе
>   "У Лукоморья Дуб спилили"). Правда, некоторые ученые полагают, что это
>   граф Л.Н. Толстой, в чьих владениях находился тот самый Дуб, и спилил
>   его (см. ЯСНЫЙ ПЕНЬ ) в личных целях. К сожалению, это было последнее
>   Мировое дерево, так как с ростом населения во всем мире извели
>   священные дубовые рощи: "Порубили все дубы на гробы".
>
> **По преданиям, ДУБ имел три яруса. Быть сброшенным богами с самого
>   верхнего из них, т.е. рухнуть с дуба - считалось высшей мерой
>   наказания.** Поэтому кроме названия «древо жизни», «древо восхождения»,
>   «древо познания» за ДУБОМ закрепились и другие, более редкие варианты:
>   «древо смерти», «древо зла», «древо нисхождения». ДУБ всегда считался
>   символом красоты, мощи и плодородия, поэтому когда хотели кому-либо
>   польстить, говорили: "Ну ты и Дуб!" или Дубак (дубовый чувак). А про
>   женщин говорили: Дубина (уменьш.-ласк.Дубинушка).

I will not translate this whole thing, just the relevant part:

> According to the legend, the Oak Tree has three layers. To be thrown down by gods from the top layer (i.e. рухнуть с дуба) was considers the most severe of punishments. That's why apart from the names "the tree of life", "the tree of ascent", "the tree of knowledge", the oak tree has also some rarer names such as "the tree of death", "the tree of evil", "the tree of descent".

Comment: *"Порубили все дубы на гробы"* - Именно что лукроморья больше нет.

Comment: Armen, I'm pretty sure it's a joke, like [all the other entries in that blog](http://ru-ace.livejournal.com/) :)

Comment: @VitalyMijiritsky: Maybe you're right, maybe you're not :)

Comment: I'd add something to this perfectly sound theory. The oak tree was so high that its top was covered with snow and ice (hence the word *дубак* for freezing cold). Also, a human life in all its misery was considered a punishment: a permanent struggle with the spirit of oak. The gods only allowed to die a person who won in this fight. Hence the expressions *дал дуба* and *врезал дуба* (originally, *дал дубу* or *врезал дубу*).

Comment: That theory sounds like something Pelevin would write.

Comment: Nice joke=) It does remind though of Scandinavian myths where there is a high asp tree, Iggdrasil, that grows through 3 worlds and constitutes the base of the universum.

Comment: @Quassnoi I'm pretty sure that "дубак" comes from "дубеть\задубеть", i.e. to become hard as wood because of cold.

Comment: Also, *дубина стоеросовая* is in no way a compliment =))

Comment: @Olga: so you don't subscribe to my theory? That's a pity, it's so sound.

Comment: @Quassnoi I do, but not officially.

Comment: @Quassnoi I guess Absurdopedia will feature it if you just elaborate a bit :)

Answer (score 3):

*Ты с дуба рухнул* = Are you crazy? (literary, *Have you fallen down from an oak tree?*)

Earliest mention in the corpus in this form:

> ― Зуенко, ты, что ли? Ты что, с дуба рухнул? Дергать нужно через счет 502-503-504.*[Василий Гулин. Прыгом-марш! (1997) // «Столица», 1997.07.15]*

The meaning is quite clear (falling from an oak tree does not make a person more sane), and the similar expressions exist in other languages: "Did your mom drop you on your head?"

I believe the wording of this expression is originated from a popular topsy-turvy Russian folklore motive of a mosquito falling down from an oak tree and causing havoc:

> Полетел комарище в лесище,
>   Садился комар на дубище,
>   Дуб под ним зашатался,
>   Комар весьма испугался,
>   Стукнуло, грянуло в лесе,
>   Комар **с дуба свалился**,
>   Упал он на коренище,
>   Сбил до костей плечище
>
> *Чуковский К. От двух до пяти*
>
> Глас народа мне вещал:
>   **С дуба-де комар упал.**
>   Се по лесу звук раздался,
>   Холм и дол восколебался,
>   Океан встал из брегов.
>
> *Державин Г. Р. Похвала Комару*

Comment: It predates 1997 for sure.  Was a widely used phrase in school which I finished in 1991

Comment: A bit earlier reference: Ты че, с дуба рухнула? ― Давай того, костистого, выманивай от меня. [Нина Садур. Немец (1996)]

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to leave this as an answer though no proof of this I could find.

The character of a Black Cat from [Понедельник начинается в Субботу](http://lib.ru/STRUGACKIE/ponedelx.txt) could have served as a prototype for this.  Given how forgetful he was it might have been assumed that he has fallen off the (oak) tree and hit his head.

Whether or not it's true may be lost to posterity.

Answer (score 0):

This particuar form of this phrase is marked as youthspeak (молодежный жаргон), so it looks like it is a quite modern invention:

> **Рухнуть с дуба**
> Жарг. мол. Неодобр. Сойти с ума, начать вести себя подобно сумасшедшему. СИ, 1998, № 6; Вахитов 2003, 160. [Большой словарь русских поговорок](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/proverbs/20813/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C).

Personally I recall that we used similar expression in elementary school: "[Упал] с дуба на кактус[, с кактуса на дуб]" in the end of 80-es.

The dictionary of russian argot also has several entries that I was unable to find in Russian National Corpus:

> **Упасть с дерева** (свалиться, рухнуть, брякнуться с березы) повести себя странно, неумно, неуместно, всех удивить; сойти с ума. - [Словарь русского арго](http://russian_argo.academic.ru/13398)

This one looks almost the same as expression in question, though I was unable to find any other references to its usage and time when it was first recorded. I believe that Морд. here stands for [Мордовия](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F):

> **Сорваться с дуба** - Морд. Неодобр. Потерять выдержку, самообладание. СРГМ 2002, 108. [Большой словарь русских поговорок](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/proverbs/20814/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F)

Also there are a lot of similar expressions that have a long history:

> ― Да ты что? **С луны свалился**? Не знаешь разве, что красная армия отступила? [Елизавета Скобцова (Кузьмина-Караваева). Равнина Русская (хроника наших дней) (1924)]
>
> Чего на своих орете, **как с гвоздя сорвались**? [Юрий Бондарев. Горячий снег (1969)]
>
> ...одни люди *с крюку*, а другие, глядя на сих мудреных предводителей и начальников зла, **с дубу** ругают, поносят и проклинают мстителей, а об обидчиках не говорят ни слова, как бы они не имели пристойного человечеству дарования, то-есть здравого ума, чтоб рассудить, кто был начальник и родитель зла, мститель ли или обидчик... [Я. П. Козельский. Философические предложения, сочиненные надворным советником и правительствующего сената секретарем Яковом Козельским в Санкт-Петербурге 1768 года (1768)]

The latter example shows that "с дубу" was used for a long time as "without reason":

> **как с дубу(рвет)**
> иноск.: придирается без причины, бестолково, зря. [Большой толково-фразеологический словарь Михельсона 1896—1912](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/michelson_new/3928/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA).

So, though the origin of the expression is not clear, there are many other expressions that were used for a long time with the same structure and meaning and referensing "упасть", "сорваться", "дуб" or any other tree.